# Android - How validate UI elements of view pager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using from [this library (ViewPagerArrowIndicator)](https://github.com/sembozdemir/ViewPagerArrowIndicator) for registration form.

I inserted in each fragment `EditText` and `RadioButton` .... .

Problem :

How can I validate them (`EditText` ....) for empty or not empty when going to another page of `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very raw example. However it give you a hint on how to get access to your `EditText` inside each next fragment.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            ...
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Fragment fragment = viewPagerAdapter.getItem(position - 1);
                if (position == 1) {
                    EditText editText = (EditText) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    String text = editText.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an [OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) to your viewpager and do the validation inside `onPageSelected`

Comment: How can I get elements of fragments in class of viewPager ?!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no simple API to get the fragments of a viewpager. Most of the solution that are there on internet, are practically reverse engineered by going through the viewpager adapter source code. However you can do some basic design strategies which will roughly help you. Go through this link - https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter#dynamic-viewpager-fragments

Comment: You can define a validate method inside your fragments and call that